# Can you please help me Identify this font in the picture?

Tags: fonts

Please help me Identify the font in this picture.[image]

Comment: Is the font supposed to be blurry like that? If yes, have you tried any of the online font identification tools? If no, can you get a sharper image?

Comment: The site identifont.com might help. It's fun and easy to use.